# Finding the maximum weighted directed cycle graph in a symmetric graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let G = (V, E) be a directed symmetric weighted Graph. If there is an edge from vertex u to v, there will always be an edge from v to u, but these two edges don't have to have the same weight, because it's a directed graph. The graph does not allow self-loops (an edge (u,u)). I want to find the maximum weighted cycle graph (A graph which has the same start and end vertex, but no other identical vertices or edges). The weight of a cycle being the sum of the weight of the edges of the graph. But I can't just simply use the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), like it is suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456935/graph-how-to-find-minimum-directed-cycle-minimum-total-weight).

The problem is if I passed the edge from u to v I can't use the edge from v to u anymore. (Imagine a bridge, which you can pass in both directions but once you used the bridge it collapses.)

My first idea was to find the pair that maximises dist(u,v)+dist(v,u), but if I found the heaviest path from u to v I have to remove the correlating edges and then find the heaviest path from v to u with those edges. This seems to be pretty overkill for this problem but I can't think of an better way.

So I want to ask if there is a better way/algorithm to find this cycle. I also need all edges of this cycle.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this at least as hard as deciding whether a graph has  a Hamiltonian cycle? The latter problem is NP-complete. What makes your problem hard is that you don't allow for vertices+edges to be repeated. Otherwise if you had a positive cycle the solution would be infinite

Comment: Niklas B. is right: It's not too hard to reduce Hamiltonian Path to this problem.  Specifically, make a new graph in which there is a vertex v' for each of the n vertices v in the original HP instance, and whenever there is an edge uv in the original HP instance, create two weight-1 edges, u'v' and v'u', in the new graph.  Now solve this instance of your problem.  If and only if there was a HP in the original graph, then there must be a corresponding directed cycle of weight n in the new instance, which solving your problem would reveal since there cannot be any heavier-weight cycle.

Comment: Does it make a difference when the weights of the edges can be negative?